# Injection from infinite Cartesian product

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

> Define $(0,1)^{\infty}$ as the infinite Cartesian product $(0,1) \times (0,1) \times \cdots$. Find an injection $ f: (0,1)^{\infty} \to (0,1)$.

I know how to write an injection from $(0,1)^2 \to (0,1)$. Take two fractions, take their decimal expansions that don't contain an infinitely long string of nine's, and then alternate decimal places. I do not know how to extend this to the case of $(0,1)^{\infty}$. I can take a countable set of infinite decimals, disallow an  infinitely long string of nine's, but I can't "alternate" in the same way because then I'll never finish the first digit after the decimal point. If I alternate, e.g., first take the first digit, then the second, then the third, I can't guarantee that the entirety of each decimal is equal.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe think diagonally?

Answer (score 1):

For $x \in (0,1)$, and $p\geq 1$, let $x(p)$ be the $p-$th decimal of $x$.

Define $f : (0,1)^{\mathbb{N}} \rightarrow (0,1)$ for any sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in (0,1)^{\mathbb{N}}$ by
$$\forall p\geq 1, \quad\left[f((x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}})\right](p) =  \begin{cases}
      x_{k}(l) &\text{if } p=2^k3^l \text{ for some } k,l \in \mathbb{N} \\
       0 & \text{otherwise} \\
     \end{cases}$$

You can prove that $f$ is an injection.

Comment: Very elegant. $ $

Answer (score 0):

An element of $(0,1)^{\mathbb N}$ is a sequence taking values in $(0,1)$. And an element of $(0,1)$ is a binary sequence, i.e. an element of $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$.

Finally an element of $(0,1)^{\mathbb N}$ can be seen as an element of $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N \times \mathbb N}$.

Now if $\phi$ is a bijection from $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ onto $\mathbb N$, define $\{a_{\phi(n,m)}\}$ as the image of $\{a(n,m) \mid (n,m) \in \mathbb N^2\}$.

Comment: I was thinking of $f:0.a_{11}a_{12}a_{13}a_{14}...,$ $0.a_{21}a_{22}a_{23}a_{24}..., 0.a_{31}a_{32}a_{33}a_{34}...,...$ $\mapsto $ $0.a_{11}a_{12}a_{21}a_{13}a_{22}a_{31}a_{14}...$.  Would that work?  Is that the same as your answer?

Comment: That is a similar answer. On your side you picked up a specific $\phi$ while I let this selection  open. By the way my answer can have the issue of almost equal to one image sequence. Which is not the case of Brian answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$0.\color{red}{a_{11}}0\color{red}{a_{12}a_{21}}0\color{red}{a_{13}a_{22}a_{31}}0\color{red}{a_{14}a_{23}a_{32}a_{41}}0\ldots$$

Comment: The downvote is useless without an explanation.

Comment: I'm wondering why you inserted the $0$s.  (I didn't downvote)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: To avoid the problem of terminal nines. It may be unnecessary in this case — I didn’t try to construct an ambiguous case — but it’s safe and harmless, since we know where they are.

Comment: I don’t understand either the downvote. +1.